# Reading a formatted text in C++

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I have been trying to read a formatted text into my C++ program, and I have found a solution. Yet, I am not content with the elegance/style of my code, and I am asking for your help to find out if there is any better solution to my problem.

I need to load the [**rcv1**](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/jmlr/papers/volume5/lewis04a/lyrl2004_rcv1v2_README.htm) dataset to my program. The dataset, as you may have already known, provides the vectorized content in the format `<did> [<tid>:<weight>]+`, where **did**, **tid** and **weight** denote the **document id**, **term id** and **weight of the corresponding term**, respectively. Each line in a file in the dataset contains a unique document id, and there are different number of **[tid,weight]** pairs for that document.

I have found a solution to loading the data as follows (below is a code excerpt from a loop in my program):

```
while( docCount < docPerW ) {
    getline( docsFile, line );

    if ( docsFile.eof() ) {
        docsFile.close();
        docPos = 0;

        fileID++;
        if ( fileID >= numFiles ) {
            topsFile.close();
            tag = 1;
            break;
        }

        docsFile.open( dataFolder + docFName +
            to_string( fileID ) + ".dat" );
        docsFile.seekg( docPos );
        continue;
    }

    istringstream docsStream( line );

    docsStream >> docDocID;
    map< int, double > docData;

    while( docsStream >> tID >> docDelim >> tWeight)
        docData[ tID ] = tWeight;

    documents[ docDocID ] = docData;
    docCount++;
}
```

Above, the file reading takes place in a master-worker setting. Each worker needs to read up to **docPerW** documents if there still exist files to read from. The **topsFile** is another file object, which I need to read the topics from (this is not relavent to my question).

In summary, is there a better way to read the terms and their weights related to a document given in such a format than
1. getting the line first,
2. then converting it to an **istringstream** object, and,
3. finally reading from that object until the stream ends?

Thanks for your help and suggesstions.

Comment: I believe this is a regex problem. Somebody should be able to come along and help you with that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Then, maybe I should also add a [tag:regex] tag, as well.

Comment: You should consider your treatment of `docDocID` broken.You are reading from the variable although you have no guarantee that it contains a meaningful value, i.e. that the previous extraction operation succeeded. The same is true for `line` (you're only checking for `eof`, not failure). I'd say that's a symptomatic misunderstanding of I/O and I'd treat the entire code as suspect.

Comment: Thanks, Kerrek, for your comment. The dataset is generated from meaningful data, and each line starts with a correct document id. For my purpose, I do not need to verify it. I mean, the document id in each line is followed by a whitespace, and I assume there does not occur any problem/exception when reading an integer value (I have also checked the ranges for the document id) from the beginning of each line, unless the line is the end of file.

Comment: You could also try and use a printf() or a string stream.

Comment: Hey, Clinch. Thanks again, for your time. I try to avoid using old language elements like **printf** to promote the usage of objects and stream operators. As for the **stringstream** suggesstion, I cannot see any difference between the two in [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/). Do you think there might be a performance difference? After all, both of them will be used in the same style, right? Or, am I missing something?

Comment: stringstream is the combination of both the input and output versions of stringstream, I believe. I may be wrong, but there is almost no difference.